# What does the team score mean in Junkenstein's Revenge?

Tags: overwatch

At the end of every game of Junkenstein's Revenge there are some partially filled stars and a team score, I've noticed that more team score means more stars.

But aside from general interest in accruing stars, is there any benefit to a higher team score?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Score is just score, and it only matters in the scoreboard.